# How is this equation deduced?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-regression, multivariate-distribution

These two equations are from the book Gaussian Process for Machine Learning. First we already have equation (2.8).

$p(\mathbf{w}|X, \mathbf{y}) ∼ N (\frac1{\sigma_n^2}A^{−1}X\mathbf{y}, A^{−1})$ (2.8)

$\int \mathbf{x}_*^T\mathbf{w}\ p(\mathbf{w}|X,\mathbf{y})d\mathbf{w} = N (\frac1{\sigma_n^2}\mathbf{x}_*^TA^{−1}X\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}_*^T A^{−1}\mathbf{x}_*)$ (2.9)

I cannot deduce equation (2.9). I just don't know how to put $\mathbf{x}_*$ into the gaussian expression. Could anybody please explain how this is deduced to me?

Comment: (2.9) merely expresses the linearity of expectation and bilinearity of covariance.

Comment: This seems strange to me actually. (2.9} is just the expectation of $x_{*}^Tw$ with respect to $w$. It should not be a Gaussian random variable. In fact, it should be just equal to $x_{*}^TE[w]$ which is the first expression in $N()$ in (2.9). The right hand side of (2.9) gives the probability distribution of $x_*^Tw$.